# How to drag windows to another workspace from the spread view?

Tags: unity

How to drag windows to another workspace from the "Spread view"?

EDIT: Seems to have created some misunderstandings by using the term "Spread View". I am referring to SUPER + W " Spread windows view" and not to SUPER + S "Spread worksheet view" aka "Workspace Switcher".

Comment: You should be able to simply drag and drop unmaximized windows. Are  you using the default desktop environment or did you change it to Unity2D?

Comment: From "Spread View" SUPER + W whenever I click on a window it just activates it. I see not other workspaces, nothing. And yes I have the full Unity.

Comment: Suoer + S is spread. Super + W is scale. You want the first one.

Comment: I do not want (Workspace switcher) SUPER + S. I want to do it from Super +W where I have a nice "explosion" with all my opened windows for a give workspace.

Answer (score 3):

From the *spread view* (<kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) just grab the window and drop it on another workspace.

P.S.: It seems as though there was a slight misunderstanding with what you regarded as the *spread view*.  You can always hold down <kbd>SUPER</kbd> to see all Unity shortcuts and their effects in a nifty overview.

Comment: Yeah I now realize both are called Spread... one spreads windows one spreads workspaces. I want SUPER + W = Spread Windows

Comment: Ok, that function is called scale and does not support window management over multiple workspaces. It only shows you all windows in your current workspace and does not support moving windows to another one.

Comment: That is sad since it seems to me to be the most natural way to move windows around workspaces with mouse :(.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by the "spread view". But if I have a window that is in focus, and I want to put it on another workspace, I usually do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> (or Left).

Comment: I know about the keyboard short-cuts. I find them awkward and hard tot use since I have to move my hand off the mouse. What I am looking for is a similar way to move windows with mouse to another workspace just like from "Workspace switcher" but from the "Spread view" SUPER + W.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: This answer refers CCSM (`compiz-config-settings-manager`) which should be used with care. There is a probability of locking yourself out of Unity if handled improperly.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> spreads all windows in the current workspace. I assume that is what you are referring to.

It is possible to bind these events to keyboard shortcuts or mouse clicks (with or without modifiers) Left click selects a window and can not be changed as far as I know.

- Zoom into a window, but do not select it
- Close a window
- Pull window

These features are handled by Scale Addons plugin in CCSM. The plugin does have an option to bind a shortcut to `pull Window`. Probably that does what you want. Screenshots are provided below for reference.

[image: CCSM scale]

[image: CCSM Scale Addons]

The problem is, I haven't yet figured how to spread all windows from all workspaces. No combination worked, yet. You can try various combinations in Scale plugin to see if you can achieve this. Once you spread all windows from all workspaces, the shortcut assigned to `Pull window` should do the trick.

Comment: Ty for your elaborate answer. It was detailed, clear and on the subject. Unfortunately I cannot make PULL work no matter what key combination I assign :(. Did you manage to pull windows?

Comment: As a side note. From experimenting with Scale Addons I found out you can assign a Close Window button in Spread View (For me Middle mouse Press).